# SQL Server Error log - strange date

Tags: sql-server, error-log

The dates in the SQL Server error log look very strange. 
A subset for messages between Sep/29/2014 8:00 am and Sep/29/5:40pm show a date of Feb/16/2014. Have you seen this before? Any idea why the date would look different?

[image: Strange_dates_inerrorlog]

Comment: Any chance your system (either the server or client) went through a clock change? I forget if the viewer converts the server time to client time (I know the SQL Server Agent log does something like this) but I suspect someone was fiddling with the clock.

Comment: Correct I guess you can check event viewer it will log system date change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that at 2/16/2014 12:23:46 AM the error message states that the instance has been using a process ID since 9/19/2014, I would suspect the system clock was rolled back after the instance startup. If this would be true we would also expect SSPI handshakes to fail due to clock difference between parties, and sure enough there are SSPI failures logged while the clock was adrift.

Comment: +1 wonder if this is to defeat a 180-day eval thing

Comment: Thank you so much. yes, that line got me thinking something was amiss. This is likely what happened, the accounts got locked out because I did get the SSPI error but then I was told, I locked the account...and I think something changed at the o/s level....checking logs

Comment: SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed   [CLIENT: 192.168.45.242]

Comment: Should I look at the system clock of the CLIENT: 192.168.45.242 or the server it is trying to connect? The original image is for the server it is trying to connect to.

Comment: @Debbie: the errorlog time is always the server time

Comment: Per the sysadmin, the server crashed multiple times and could not update the close. It is now resolved. Thank you all for your responses. It was very useful.